# How can I create Azure AD group memberships using Terraform?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform

I'm trying to create Group Memberships in an Azure AD group for the purpose of inheriting the other group's access

I can do this in the Azure portal here:
[Azure Portal Group Membership Blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGIrv.png)

But I can't figure out how to do this with powershell/azure-cli or terraform

Is this even possible ?  If not, is there a workaround for it ?

Comment: Are you looking for terraform template ?

Comment: @Revan Yes, or a way to do it via powershell or azure-cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure support got back to me with a solution:

There's 2 ways to do this with powershell:

#### With the msonline module (this does not directly work in powershell core)

```
> Add-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $groupid -GroupMemberType User -GroupMemberObjectId $userid
```

#### With the azuread module (this works directly in powershell core)

```
> Add-AzADGroupMember -MemberObjectId $targetGroupIdValue --TargetGroupObjectId $groupIdValue
```

Note, this solution adds a member to the other group for no apparent reason, might be a bug

Answer (score 1):

You can give it a try using the [Terraform Azure AD provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/group_member). We use it for user membership but I see there's support for a group object as well.

```
data "azuread_user" "example" {
  user_principal_name = "jdoe@hashicorp.com"
}

resource "azuread_group" "example" {
  name = "my_group"
}

resource "azuread_group_member" "example" {
  group_object_id  = azuread_group.example.id
  member_object_id = data.azuread_user.example.id
}
```

> member_object_id - (Required) The Object ID of the Azure AD Object you want to add as a Member to the Group. **Supported Object types** are Users, **Groups** or Service Principals. Changing this forces a new resource to be created.

So you would use something like this instead:

```
data "azuread_group" "example" {
  display_name     = "MyGroupName"
  security_enabled = true
}

resource "azuread_group_member" "example" {
  group_object_id  = azuread_group.example.id
  member_object_id = data.azuread_group.example.id
}
```

Comment: Added ref quote from terraform, and sample code

Comment: Thanks Ked, but what you're doing is adding the group as a member of the other group, not adding a group membership to it, those are 2 different things. The latter gives you group access inheritance which is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Oh wow. Ok now I get it, my bad - definitely something not available out of the box. So these are what are called Nested Groups, right? Terraform surely doesn't have anything for it, nor does the AZ Cli. PowerShell might but the cmdlets are so confusing... I'll ask around and get back to you but I hope someone else can give you an answer before then!

Comment: You're right, looks like they're called Nested Groups(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-groups-membership-azure-portal) Thanks for looking into it nevertheless